# php, exec, shell exec, rm cannot lstat

Tags: php

I am on WIN7, using PHP and Gnu CoreUtils 5.3.0
I need to delete recursively from a folder with mask, in instance all *.php and *.txt files.

```
exec(
    'rm -rf ../root_compressed/*.php *.txt'
    //.' '.$SILENT
    , $out, $ret);

if($ret)
    die("\nERROR!!!\n");
```

This one fails with
rm: cannot lstat `*.txt': Invalid argument

Now using

```
shell_exec(
    'rm -rf ../root_compressed/*.php *.txt'
    //.' '.$SILENT
);
```

This works.

I need exec() since I'd like to know if success or not.
What is the problem with rm?

Comment: TRy with *.php, *.txt because is an invalid argument

Comment: hmm.. none of them are working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *.txt files are also located in the root_compressed folder, you need to include that as well in your rm command:

```
exec(
    'rm -rf ../root_compressed/*.php ../root_compressed/*.txt'
    //.' '.$SILENT
    , $out, $ret);
```

You can also use curly brace expansion if your server supports it:

```
exec(
    'rm -rf ../root_compressed/*.{php,txt}'
    , $out, $ret);
```

Note that the recursive flag (`-r`) on the `rm` command won't do much in this case, since you're only looking explicitly for *.php and *.txt entries. So unless your subfolders are named like that, this will not recursively delete all *.php and *.txt from every subfolder in the root_compressed folder.

I tried getting a one-liner command to do that using `find`, but I couldn't get it to accept two file types in one argument. You'd have to use something like `find ../root_compressed -type f -name "*.php" -delete` multiple times for each file type you want to delete.

However, it's quite easy to script it yourself using the SPL library:

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../root_compressed");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && preg_match("~\.(php|txt)$~i", $file->getFilename())) {
        unlink($file->getRealpath());
    }
}
```

Comment: The curly braces will only work if exec would call bash or other shells that borrowed that feature from bash (and not a more standard shell). Hence, curly braces will probably work on Linux, and will probably not work on any unix variant that avoids gnu licenses.

Comment: @swa66 good point, I was working on an edit for the whole "recursive" part of the question when you posted that. I added an "if your server supports it" note.

Comment: Just note the OP is using win7 + tools, might be even much worse what his shell supports ... no clue: like the cleaning lady I don't do windows.

Comment: Haha likewise. Gnu CoreUtils should support it though.

Comment: unlink to me is the more portable approach anyway.

Comment: @rickdenhaan +1 and accepted because I already use php, I realized that I could use rm -rf in a foreach loop. I just delete required files later in php. Thanks!